# Manipulate React input field with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to set the value of a React input element on [this website](https://www.dhl.de/de/privatkunden/pakete-versenden/online-frankieren.html?type=ShipmentEditorAddressInput)

I tried it by:

```
var target = document.getElementById("address.receiver.name2");
target.value = "test"
```

And I can see the change. But I guess React DOM is not changing the value.

Even if I try to sent a new event by:

```
var target = document.getElementById("address.receiver.name2");
var event = new Event('keydown', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true });
event.isTrusted = true;
event.key = 'a';
target.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Nothing changes. (Does React check for the "isTrusted" flag from the event?)

How can I change values for those input fields?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you would need to state and a handler to update the state.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function DummyComponent() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (e) => {
     setvalue(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default DummyComponent;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: i am not able to import a module in the javascript console.
i pasted a link to the website where i want to edit the input fields.

Comment: the website is not mine and i want to edit those input fields by javascript.
your comment is not a solution for my question. :(